# PETSc Krylov Subspace and nullspace

Tags: petsc, fenics, conjugate-gradient, svd

How is the nullspace correction implemented in the PETSc conjugate gradient solver? I searched the source code and documentation, but could not find references on the actual implementation.

For background, I am solving linear systems arising from a bilinear form which is elliptic in a quotient space $\mathbb{R}^n\big/\ker{\mathbf{Z}}$, where $\mathbf{Z}$ is an $m \times n$ matrix having non-trivial null-space.

I compute SVD of $\mathbf{Z}$ and feed the right singular vectors corresponding to "big" singular values as nullspace vectors to the PETSc conjugate gradient solver. It works like a charm, except when $\mathbf{Z}$ is not of academic size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a projection $1 - ZZ^T$.  If you are digging around in the implementation, look at `KSP_PCApplyBAorAB()` and related functions.